# Removing lists with zero at any position

Tags: pattern-matching, list-manipulation

I want to delete the complete list within a list containing `0` at any position.

I tried using:

```
DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2], {0 ..}]
```

> {{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 0},
>       {-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1},
>       {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}

But only the lists starting with `0` are removed.

How can I remove the entire list that contains `0` at any place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2], {___, 0, ___}] (* or *)
 DeleteCases[data, {0, 0}|{1,0}|{0,1}]
```

> {{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 
>     1}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2,
>      1}, {2, 2}}

Alternatively, if you can, remove zeros from the input lists before using `Tuples`:

```
Tuples[Join[-Reverse@#, #]&@Range[2],2]
```

> same result

Even if `data = Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]` is already created, processing `data` to create a zero-free input list and using `Tuples` on it is (to my surprise) faster than using `Pick`  to remove entries with zeros from pairs of data:

```
data = Tuples[Range[-100, 100], 2];

ra = Tuples[Join[-Reverse @ #, #]& @ Range[100],2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0000524

```
rb = With[{r = DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[data], 0]},
  Tuples[r, 2]];// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000178

```
rc = Pick[data, Unitize[data].{1, 1}, 2];//RepeatedTiming//First (*from @Henrik's answer*)
```

> 0.0013

```
rd = DeleteCases[data, {0, 0}|{1,0}|{0,1}];// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.017

```
re = DeleteCases[data, {___, 0, ___}];// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.026

```
rf = Select[data, FreeQ[0] ];// RepeatedTiming // First  (*from David's answer *)
```

> 0.060

```
ra == rb == rc == rd == re == rf
```

> True

Comment: Well.... if you're free to delete 0 before using Tuples simply use `Tuples[{-2, -1, 1, 2}, 2]`.

Comment: @David, yes; i used the more cumbersome way to deal with cases like `Range[-100, 100]`

Comment: Oh, method `b` and `c`... nice out-of-the-box-thinking!

Comment: `DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[data], 0]` is not packed, while `Join[-Reverse @ #, #]& @ Range[100]` is, explaining the difference in timing

Comment: @CarlWoll, good point. But in this case, `DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[data]` (which is packed)  already takes `0.00011` seconds (RepeatedTiming)  compared to `3.06*10^-6` for  `Join[-Reverse @ #, #]& @ Range[100]`, simply because the former processes a list with dimensions `{40401,2}` and the latter with just `{200}`.

Answer (score 8):

Here a more cumbersome (not a code golfer) but faster approach:

```
data = Tuples[Range[-100, 100], 2];
a = DeleteCases[data, {___, 0, ___}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Pick[data, Unitize[data].{1, 1}, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.028
>
> 0.00098
>
> True

This skips pattern matching in favor of faster vectorized functions.

Answer (score 8):

Or...

```
Select[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2], ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]
```

or as @ThatGravityGuy points out...

```
Select[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2], FreeQ[#, 0] &]
```

Comment: Instead of `!MemberQ` couldn't you just use `FreeQ`?

Comment: Oooh... of course.  Yes.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use the operator form `FreeQ[0]` instead of `FreeQ[#, 0] &`

Comment: .. or operator forms of both `Select ` and `FreeQ`: `Select[FreeQ@0]@data`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2];
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3) with `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {{OrderlessPatternSequence[0, _]}}]
```

{{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1,
1}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2,
1}, {2, 2}}

With long lists `SequenceSplit` gets very slow

Answer (score 1):

```
Pick[#,Unitize[MapApply[Times]@#],1]&[Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]]


(* 
   {{-2,-2},{-2,-1},{-2,1},{-2,2},{-1,-2},{-1,-1},{-1,1},{-1,2},{1,-2},
    {1,-1},{1,1},{1,2},{2,-2},{2,-1},{2,1},{2,2}} 
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the entries with product of the elements zero:

```
Complement[list, Extract[list, Position[Times[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ list, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]
```

Using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, x_ /; ! FreeQ[x, 0] :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2},
   {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
Join @@ SequenceCases[list, s : {__} /; FreeQ[s, 0] :> s]

(*{{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2},
   {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}*)
```